# Loop through rows contain specific text until blank

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am having this piece of code to get all values between brackets in a cell (cell contains multiple parentheses) and paste each value into separate cells on the same row. This one only works if I point to the cell I want to split and run the code.

```
Sub Split_Value()

Dim z As Variant

z = Split(Replace(Join(Filter(Split(Replace(Replace(Selection.Value, ")", "^#"), "(", "#^"), "#"), "^"), "|"), "^", ""), "|")

Selection.Offset(0, 22).Resize(, UBound(z) + 1) = z

End Sub
```

My question is how do I create a loop to go through all cells in one Column (from top to the bottom) and only run this code in cells containing text "Accounts" and stop the code when the cell blank?

[Screenshot is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9XBs.png)

Thank you very much for your help!

Sorry I am very new to vba and macro.

Comment: Can you share some sample strings? (more than 1) and show what section you want to extract - there may be a better way to extract the data.

Comment: you can find [plenty of code (in SO itself)](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+excel+loop+through+rows&rls=com.microsoft:it-IT&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&gws_rd=ssl#spf=1570814952525) to do what you need: come back with some code and its issues (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @urdearboy I have edited the question with screenshot attached. Basically I want to code to go thru all cells in Column A, extract numbers between brackets and paste to the right. This is what I have so far. The error seems to appear when cell doesn't contain brackets.

```
Sub Split_Value()

Dim x As Integer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("A2").Select

For x = 1 To NumRows

Dim z As Variant

z = Split(Replace(Join(Filter(Split(Replace(Replace(Selection.Value, ")", "^#"), "(", "#^"), "#"), "^"), "|"), "^", ""), "|")

Selection.Offset(0, 3).Resize(, UBound(z) + 1) = z

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSydo.png)